# Photo.colorChange() opencv function is giving strange error

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I'm new to opencv concept so please do excuse me if my question is foolish. Basically I'm trying to use `Photo.colorChange()` function of `opencv`.But the problem is it's giving strange error I don't understand why. I tried to find reference in google but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Code:

```
Mat tmp = new Mat (bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);

            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, tmp);

            Mat tir=new Mat(bitmap.getWidth()/2,bitmap.getHeight()/2,CvType.CV_8UC4);
             Photo.colorChange(tmp,tmp,tir,0.5f,0.4f,0.2f);


            Utils.matToBitmap(tmp,bitmap);
```

Error:

```
CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1987: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function void cv::arithm_op(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray, int, void (**)(const uchar*, size_t, const uchar*, size_t, uchar*, size_t, cv::Size, void*), bool, void*, int)
]
    at org.opencv.photo.Photo.colorChange_0(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.photo.Photo.colorChange(Photo.java:480)
    at opengl.community.myopencvexample.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:87)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52535727/7955779) I'm getting the following new error.

New Error:

```
 CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/core/src/copy.cpp:382: error: (-215) size() == mask.size() in function void cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray) const
]
```

Comment: What is the strange error?

Comment: Please provide the full Traceback of the error ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I apologize because of not posting the error but now please check it

Comment: @ZdaR now please check it

Comment: There error message is self-explanatory: `where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels`, check the size and channels of each matrix and fix it. By inspecting the code it seems that `tir` matrix is of half the size of `tmp`, try creating `tir` with same dimensions as `tmp` and later resize it to half.

Comment: @ZdaR sir thanks a lot for your time and answer . Could you please explain these things means how to later resize it to half by an answer ? sorry I'm a beginner in this concept so I don't know how to exactly do that

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error seems to be the different size of `tmp` and `tir` matrices in line:

```
Photo.colorChange(tmp,tmp,tir,0.5f,0.4f,0.2f);
```

As you are creating `tir` using

```
Mat tir=new Mat(bitmap.getWidth()/2,bitmap.getHeight()/2,CvType.CV_8UC4);
```

so it's dimensions are half of the `tmp` dimensions. You may create `tir` as:

```
Mat tir=new Mat(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),CvType.CV_8UC4);
Photo.colorChange(tmp,tmp,tir,0.5f,0.4f,0.2f);
```

After these steps you could resize the `tir` using `Imgproc.resize()`.

Comment: Sir after following your advise I'm getting some new errors please have a look at them